# BeanCreationException while deploying IBM worklight enterprise server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are trying to deploy Worklight Enterprise edition on Ubuntu server over Tomcat

While we were successful with several steps, we got stuck with one error while getting the Tomcat up and running with our War file. We use MySQL as DB.

The specific error we are facing is ".BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'deployService' defined in URL"

SEVERE: FWLST0003E: ========= Failed starting project /td_ibm
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'deployService' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/tomcat6/lib/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/integration.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

The complete log trace text file can be found at [Tomcat Log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qi7k43fv3tha2q0/tomcat_deployment_error.txt)

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a configuration issue. 
1. run mysql-admin (MySQL UI front end) and make sure you can connect to the Worklight catalog under the name and user you defined in the worklight.properties.

1. if the database is on a different machine than the tomcat (make sure you have set the right remote access permissions for MySQL (for testing only: try giving Worklight DB user an untrusted access .i.e. use "@%" ))
2. another issue: if you are installing Worklight on Tomcat: did you run the SQL schema script to create the Worklight schema ? you must run it manually  (there is a workaround though: connect to the same database from Eclipse which runs a Worklight project)
3. what files do you have under /var/lib/tomcat6/worklight.home/td_ibm/data/export/adapters ?
   If its empty, there maybe a bug in the Worklight code.